# We could not figure out state of the Comparison Graph

Tags: git, github

I make commit every day (it is my GitHub challenge), but yesterday I forgot to commit.. so I changed date on yesterday, made commit and tried to sync.. at that moment my computer crashed and reloaded with error about lost memory.

Now I can't make commit and have error like on the screen. I have only one branch.. how can I solve it?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try and reset everything by:

- removing that repo from your list of repo managed by GitHub Desktop
- cloning the repo again (in a new path to avoid any cache effect)
- add that repo to your repos in GitHub Desktop
- replicate your change in that new local cloned repo and push.